# SerenityRest lastResponse() method returns response from previous response

Tags: java, automation, serenity-bdd

So basically in some cases my `lastresponse()` method gets stuck with a previous response and won't update to a real 'last' response.
For example if I execute this request
`SerenityRest.given() .accept("*/*") .header("X-Api-Key", "api key") .when() .get("https://randommer.io/api/Finance/Iban/".concat(countryUri)).getBody().as(String.class);`
I get back a random IBAN from the given country. When I make another request after this, and after the second request I call `restAssuredThat( lastResponse -> lastResponse.body(containsString(message)));`
The `lastResponse` will contain the first requests IBAN, instead of the second requests body. I have encountered this issue with post requests, when I use multipart to upload a file.

I have tried adding `Thread.sleep()` delays, executing two requests in the same step.

So has anyone encountered this? Is there a fix or a workaround?

Comment: Where is your second request? Don't see it. Pls provide full code to reproduce this.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 I can't provide second request due to company policy. But any request should produce the same result

Comment: Why don't you add a random request to demonstrate your problem?